# What does this for SEO: dynamic content generated by JavaScript, pulled from json service

Tags: javascript, json, seo, jsonp

I wonder what this does for SEO:

Say I got a backoffice that contains articles, and that is accessible via a JSON service.
I would then use JSONP to fetch, and render the data using JavaScript as follows:

```
<body>
<script src="http://myjsonservice.com/getarticles?callback=myRender" />
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myRender(jsonObj){
       //parse the object, and put it as children to the content-container div below
       ...
   }
</script>
<div id="content-container"></div>
</body>
```

I got a strong feeling this hurts SEO, but I am a SEO newbie (i've heard many pages with hardcoded content is somewhat optimal as far as indexing goes).

But is the content from the JSON service indexed AT ALL by Google? Ie. do the bots hit the url, let JS modify the DOM, and index the in-memory DOM (rather than the hardcoded html markup only)?

I wonder what you all think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think client side processed html is processed by search engine bots. You have to add keywords in the header of the page or something. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278188/javascript-based-redirect-will-it-hurt-seo), especially the phrase: *In general, searchbots should be treated as browsers with JS disabled*

Answer (score 0):

Hard coded text is better for SEO, because most crawlers quite simply take the page's code as it is served initially when they are parsing and indexing, so quite simply any text added by JS will be missed by the spiders.